# Implementation of img_caption_shortcode has no effect

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've added the following code in my childs functions.php

```
add_filter( 'img_caption_shortcode', 'my_img_caption_shortcode', 10, 3 );
function my_img_caption_shortcode( $output, $attr, $content ) {
    $attr = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id'      => '',
        'align'   => 'alignnone',
        'width'   => '',
        'caption' => ''
    ), $attr );

    if ( 1 > (int) $attr['width'] || empty( $attr['caption'] ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    if ( $attr['id'] ) {
        $attr['id'] = 'id="' . esc_attr( $attr['id'] ) . '" ';
    }

    return '<div ' . $attr['id']
    . 'class="wp-caption ' . esc_attr( $attr['align'] ) . '" '
    . 'style="max-width: ' . ( 10 + (int) $attr['width'] ) . 'px;">'
    . do_shortcode( $content )
    . '<p class="wp-caption-text">TEST TEST' . $attr['caption'] . '</p>'
    . '</div>';
}
```

Nevertheless, all images within the_content are output in the post as follows:

```
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><img loading="lazy" width="960" height="637" src="https://www.example.com/img.jpg" alt="example" class="wp-image-9987" srcset=" (...) "><figcaption>My caption text</figcaption></figure>
```

The above hook doesn't seem to have **any effect**.

The content of the post is read in the single.php using the_content().

- The cache is cleared
- Latest WP version
- no error message

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure that the `img_caption_shortcode()` function is being called. In our case, someone had added a custom shortcode handler a few years ago and the custom handler did not apply the `img_caption_shortcode` filter.